# Fastest way to iterate over ordered pairs of HashMap entries

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

The below code uses `O(N^2)` time to process all ordered pairs of a `HashMap`. In this example I can not use another data structure such as a `TreeMap` so wondering if it is possible to improve the iteration time? Java 8 idioms are welcomed. I thought maybe to use a `months filter by condition` logic where condition could be expressed using lambda notation as `months filter ( (l, r) -> (l < r) )`. If data was stored in a sorted `ArrayList`, then this iteration would take `O(N^2 / 2)` which is faster by a factor of `2` and also the best-time complexity.

```
Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
months.put("January", 1);
months.put("February", 2);
months.put("March", 3);
months.put("April", 4);
months.put("May", 5);
months.put("June", 6);
months.put("July", 7);
months.put("August", 8);
months.put("September", 9);
months.put("October", 10);
months.put("November", 11);
months.put("December", 12);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : months.entrySet()) {
    String month = entry.getKey();
    Integer index = entry.getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2 : months.entrySet()) {
        Integer index2 = entry2.getValue();
        if (index < index2) {
            // process ordered pair of months
            String month2 = entry2.getKey();
            System.out.println(month + " " + month2);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I have found my soluttion - I need to use`LinkedHashMap` which preserves the order months are inserted that is I can get all pairs with `O(N^2 / 2)` like if I was using `ArrayList`.

Comment: `O(N^2)` and `O(N^2/2)` are the same time complexity.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but practically you will feel the difference.

Comment: There is no "theoretically". The [Landau symbols have a strict mathematical definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Comment: If you want to compare each value to each other value, you can never do better than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Man, you are talking about theory. Maths is theory. Try and run it and you will see the difference!!!

Comment: So I think this can not be done faster right?

Comment: Time complexity is not the same thing as performance. If you don't want theory and maths, don't talk about time complexity.

Comment: No Stephan, he is correct. The runtime can be faster but the complexity is exactly the same. He is not saying that `O(n)` is as fast as `O(n/20)`, he is simply noting that it's the same complexity. And as your input size grows, the time-difference will converge to zero.

Comment: @StephanRozinsky This most certainly can be done faster, just not asymptotically. But the improvement would hardly be worth your time unless it's of *major* importance, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Although the intention is clear (and the unfortunate wording about "complexity" caused this point to be missed), it might be relevant to know what is actually done with these pairs. As others have pointed out, the *iteration* itself will hardly be a problem. And **if** it is a problem: Use a `LinkedHashSet`. There, the iteration tends to be (noticably) faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity is identical. Specifically,

> O(N<sup>2</sup>)

and

> O(N<sup>2</sup> / 2)

are the same complexity class.  This is a mathematically provable fact.

It is also true that even though N<sup>2</sup> is greater than N<sup>2</sup> / 2 ... but this is not the characterization that "Big O" notation is explaining.

The other thing to consider is that cost of sorting the list is often going to be more than your saving of N^2 / 2.  Either way, you need to include that cost in your overall calculations.

---

My gut feeling is that you would be better of implementing the alternatives (in your larger application) and *measuring* the performance<sup>1</sup>.  You are asking for advice that goes beyond "ordinary" complexity analysis, and that takes us quickly into the realm of behaviours of specific library methods, compilers, etcetera.  AFAIK, there is no *practical* way to get answers that you can rely on ... other than by empirical measurement.

But before you do that, you should *profile* your application to make sure that you aren't wasting your time optimizing something that has no significant impact on *overall* performance.

---

<sup>1 - Especially since your latest comments have thrown multi-threaded performance into an already too-complicated problem.</sup>

Comment: Since `O(n log n + n^2 / 2) = O(n^2)` it doesn't really matter, does it. However, I do believe there will be a minor increase by sorting first as `n log n` is definitely better than the other `n^2/2`. - And by minor increase I don't mean asymptotically but for small inputs obviously.

Comment: If I want to sort my hashmap, do I need to copy its elements into a list first or I can do that with the map keys?

Comment: @ShellFish why `O(n log n + n^2 / 2) = O(n^2)`?

Comment: Because it's not exact arithmetic, take a look at the definition of the "big-oh" notation and you will see why. Asymptotically they have the exact same complexity. Let me give you a few more examples: `O(n) = O(20n+1'000'000)`, `O(n^2) = O(n^2 + n)` and `O(n^2) = O(n^2 + log n)`.

Comment: @StephanRozinsky - Because ... mathematics.  Do the math.  A proof from first principles is obvious.

Comment: A HashMap itself can't be sorted, that's not the point of the datastructure. Copying the elements to a List of some sort would require another `O(n)` but you still might profit on small input. Either way, the conclusion is simple: don't bother.

Comment: @ShellFish - You are correct (your first comment).  I was simply making a point in terms that I thought that the OP would understand.

Comment: @StephanRozinsky - If you want to avoid an explicit sort step, then use `TreeMap<Integer, String>`.  However, you still get an `O(NlogN`) in the complexity.

Comment: Am I right that `TreeMap` is bad in parallel app when multiple threads are trying to insert data? That is why I ideally tend to `HashMap` and its Concurrent version.

Comment: See my latest answer update.  (Besides, by throwing concurrency into the mix at the last minute ... you are CHANGING the problem ...)